# MIPS Assembly: Convert from Integer to Hexadecimal

Tags: assembly, type-conversion, mips

I found this code snippet that I believe converts an integer to hex.  However, I'm not following it at all.  I added the comments that say what I believe is happening, but I have no idea WHY it's being done.  So, assuming I correctly noted what each line was doing, can someone please explain to me why it's being done? As in how it in any way helps convert to hex?

$a0 is the integer value

$a1 is the address of where the result should be

```
        addi $t0, $0, 48       #set $t0 equal to 48 
        sb $t0, 0($a1)         #store $to (48) at location 0 in $a1
        addi $t0, $0, 120      #set $t0 equal to 120
        sb $t0, 1($a1)         #store $t0 (120) at location 1 in $a1
        addi $t1, $a1, 9       #set $t1 = the address + 9

LOOP:

        andi $t0, $a0, 0xf    #$t0 = 1 if $a0 and 0xf are the same (0xf = beginning of hex)?

        slti $t2, $t0, 10     #if $t0 is less than 10, $t2 = 1, else 0
        bne $t2, $0,  DIGIT   #if $t2 does not equal 0, branch to DIGIT
        addi $t0, $t0, 48     #set $t0 equal to 48
        addi $t0, $t0, 39     #set $t0 equal to 39 (why did we just write over the 48?)
DIGIT:

        sb $t0, 0($t1)        #set $t0 equal to whatever's in location 0 of $t1

        srl $a0, $a0, 4       #shift right 4 bits

        bne $a0, $0, LOOP     #if $a0 does not equal 0, branch to LOOP
        addi $t1, $t1, -1     #set $t1 = $t1 - 1

DONE:

        jr $ra                #set the jump register back to $ra
        nop
```

Comment: [Why is my MIPS base converter printing out the values from a previous loop after the current values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37153381) has working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    slti $t2, $t0, 10     #if $t0 is less than 10, $t2 = 1, else 0
    bne $t2, $0,  DIGIT   #if $t2 does not equal 0, branch to DIGIT
    addi $t0, $t0, 48     #set $t0 equal to 48
    addi $t0, $t0, 39     #set $t0 equal to 39 (why did we just write over the 48?)
```

MIPS uses branch delay slots, meaning that the instruction following the branch instruction always is executed before the branch is taken (or not taken).

So what this says is "If $t0 is less than 10 (i.e. in the range 0..9), goto DIGIT, but first add 48 (ASCII '0') regardless of the value of $t0. In case the branch was taken you'll now have converted from 0..9 to '0'..'9'. In case the branch wasn't taken, $t0 was originally in the range 10..15 and will now be in the range 58..63, so we add 39 more to get a value in the range 97..102 (the ASCII codes for 'a'..'f')".

Comment: ohhh so he's converting it to ASCII and then the ASCII code goes into each individual digit?

Comment: Sort of. The end result is a string, which is just an array of (ASCII) characters.

Comment: Ah... I didn't realize hex was a string.  Figured it was a number written in a different format.  That definitely helps.. Thanks!

Comment: Hexadecimal doesn't automatically mean a string. But conversion between different bases doesn't make much sense unless there's a textual representation involved. For plain numbers there's no difference (the values 20 and 0x14 are represented by exactly the same bit patterns).

Comment: Real MIPS uses branch-delay slots, but MARS / SPIM *don't* (I mention this because half the MIPS questions on SO are about these simulators).  Fun fact: recent updates to the MIPS ISA added new branch instructions that *don't* have a branch-delay slot.  Exposing details of the pipeline like this was good in the 1980s, but less good for superscalar / out-of-order execution MIPS where it's an inconvenience to support.

Comment: MARS / SPIM can be configured to have branch delay slots. But I believe the default is no delay slots.